# How to display values in a better way in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I have a question about SwiftUI. I have been trying to display the game scores like in the image:
[View to show scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KCn4.jpg)

They can be displayed but the problem is that the text (eg. the score for 10 questions) moves DOWN a bit when the scores are deleted and I think that is not great. I want to know how to fix the text.

```
VStack {
    Text("The score for 10 questions")
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .bold()
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 210,height: 2)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .padding(.bottom,10)
    
        ForEach(Array(playerItems.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, item in
            if offset == 0 {
                Text("Best score : \(item.playerScore)")
            }
            else if offset == 1 {
                Text("2nd score : \(String(item.playerScore))")
            }
            else if offset == 2 {
                Text("3rd score : \(String(item.playerScore))")
                  
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .bold()
        .onTapGesture {
            do {
                try context.delete(model: PlayerItem.self)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to clear all Country and City data.")
            }
        }
}
.frame(height: 100)
```

I followed the tutorial.

Comment: Also consider not using absolute sizes for the frames. User may, for example, increase font size, and then text will look cut off. Instead, use relative sizes, and control number of lines for text (e.g. `.maxLines(2)`

Comment: This is an excellent start! Please consider using a fixed-width font and standardizing your score output to a uniform number of digits. Otherwise you will see movement when the score requires an additional digit (from '8' to '10' or '99' to '100' for example)  

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting a fixed height of 100 on the `VStack`. By default, the content it contains is shown vertically centered inside this space.

To fix, add `alignment: .top` to the `.frame` modifier:

```swift
VStack {
    // content as before
}
.frame(height: 100, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: Or just add a `Spacer()` below the content

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Adding a `Spacer` will always leave a space at the bottom, caused by the `spacing` of the `VStack`. Also, 100 is probably too little if the scores are actually present. If no alignment is specified then it overflows top and bottom, which always causes jumping around. Adding a `Spacer` makes this symtom worse, due to the extra space at the bottom.